# Run command creates pod instead of deployment on Azure Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, selenium-grid, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks, kubernetes-deployment

When I use the kubectl run command instead of creating a deployment it creates a pod/selenium-node-chrome and as a result, I am unable to scale the selenium-node-chrome using the replicas command.

```
PS C:\Users\Test> kubectl run selenium-node-chrome --image selenium/node-chrome:latest --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub" --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444"
pod/selenium-node-chrome created
PS C:\Users\Test> kubectl scale deployment selenium-node-chrome --replicas=5
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "selenium-node-chrome" not found
```

The video tutorial that I followed successfully created deployment "selenium-node-chrome" after running the same command. Please I need help and I am new to Kubernetes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a generator

```
kubectl run selenium-node-chrome \
  --image selenium/node-chrome:latest \
  --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub" \
  --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444" \
  --generator=deployment/apps.v1beta1
```

https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#generators

Comment: Still pod gets created                                                                                                           
PS C:\Users\Test> kubectl run selenium-node-chrome --image selenium/node-chrome:latest --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=s
elenium-hub" --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444" --generator=deployment/apps.v1beta1
Flag --generator has been deprecated, has no effect and will be removed in the future.
                                                                                                                           
pod/selenium-node-chrome created

Comment: thats not true. a deployment gets created `deployment.apps/selenium-node-chrome created` obviously a pod gets created by the deployment as well

Comment: no deployments PS C:\Users\Test> kubectl run selenium-node-chrome --image selenium/node-chrome:latest --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub" --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444" --generator=deployment/apps.v1beta1
Flag --generator has been deprecated, has no effect and will be removed in the future.
pod/selenium-node-chrome created
PS C:\Users\Test> kubectl get deployments
No resources found in default namespace.
PS C:\Users\Test> kubectl scale deployment selenium-node-chorme --replicas=5
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "selenium-node-chorme" not found

Answer (score 0):

All generators are deprecated in Kubernetes version 1.18. From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#kubectl-run)

> Note: All kubectl generators are deprecated. See the Kubernetes v1.17
>   documentation for a list of generators and how they were used.

You can use `kubectl create deployment my-dep --image=busybox` to create a deployment.

Also to create a yaml file use `kubectl create deployment my-dep --image=busybox --dry-run=client -o yaml > deployment.yaml` and then edit the yaml file to add env or any other details and apply the yaml via `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

Comment: but I can't pass on the --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub" --env="HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444" using create deployment is there any possible workaround so that I can pass --env env

Comment: just create a yaml file and use `kubectl apply`?